# Could a holodeck create smells?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, holodeck

[Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Holodeck) explains how a holodeck works as follows:

> A typical holodeck consisted of a room equipped with a hologrid
>   containing omnidirectional holographic diodes, enabling holographic
>   projections through **the manipulation of photons contained within force
>   fields.**

If this is the case, we can generate sights, feeling objects and sounds are easily to make.  My question is, though, can a smell or taste also be generated on a holodeck?

Comment: Both smell and taste are just particles touching your particles (very simplefied). That means when you smell poo, it's actually poo particles entering you and touching your receptors.

Comment: @Petersaber Precisely; but through the manipulation of photons and force fields, that doesn't make those molecules, hence the question!

Comment: an actual, legit working matter is created. Those poo molecules are there. If a holographic bullet can truly kill you, then why wouldn't you be able to taste it? It's particles all the way down (and turtles)

Comment: @Petersaber yes, which is what I say in my answer ;)

Comment: oh YOU've answered your own question o_O didn't notice that

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Yes, smells can be created

The Holodeck does work via photon manipulation and force fields, but it also uses *actual matter*:

> A holodeck **combines elements of transporter technology with that of replicators, by generating actual matter**, as well as projecting force fields to give the objects the illusion of substance.

([Source](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Holodeck))

Replication was only used for object which individuals would actually come into contact with:

> In the early 24th century, **matter replication was primarily used for
>   objects and characters that would be in direct contact with the
>   occupants** which gave them an extreme sense of realism. Water, for
>   example, would feel like actual water because on some level, it was,
>   and **it could create experiences like odors**.

([Source](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Holodeck))

In this way, not only can smells be created, but items can have a taste as well, because they are *replicated* matter.

Comment: Interesting...so if you had the holodeck re-create a restaurant, then it would use the replicators to actually create any food the occupants ate?  I want one.

Comment: <nitpicking>Transporters and replicators both have the "transporter effect" (glittering) when in action. How does the holodeck suppress this optical effect on de-/materialization and why is it not used on the replicators and transporters?</nitpicking>

Comment: @Hothie interesting point.  Considering the holodeck has the capacity to manipulate photons, it should be possible to suppress this 'glittering effect'

Comment: @Liesmith so being able to recreate a nice dining experience is the deciding factor for you wanting a holodeck? I feel as if it might be wasted on you...

Comment: @Daft don't judge me.

Comment: @Hothie As N_Soong said, plus masking the visual effect would take energy and computing power. It's a waste of resources to do it on normal transporters and replicators. In the holodeck, not doing it breaks immersion, so it's worth the resources. Plus, on the beam-out side, there are (generally speaking) no holo-emitters to do the manipulation with.

Comment: To do what ST:TNG and later shows demonstrate in their holodecks would require enormous quantities of energy - even more than they throw around in battles with other starships.  It's always been a *cringe worthy* plot point IMO.

Comment: @Hothie, the replicated matter doesn't need to be replicated where it can be seen by the people in the Holodeck. In the case of the restaurant, all replication can be done behind the kitchen door. In a bar, it can be done beforehand for the bottles on the wall and in the plumbery for taps…

Comment: @Hothie Not to mention replication takes a few seconds to fully materialize the item in question, whereas we never see any materialization lag in the holodeck. (Surely there would be some things that couldn't be replicated before hand because the computer can't always predict what a person is going to come in contact with?)

Comment: @Jim2B If I recall, at some point (pre-TNG I believe) shield technology actually involved replicating some kind of ablative material.

Comment: @Michael Regarding "replicating shields", Memory Alpha on [Ablative generator](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Ablative_generator) also mentions this: "According to Mr. Scott's Guide to the Enterprise (page 14), the deflector shields of the refit-Constitution-class were a similar technology, while only the defense fields protecting the top decks were traditional force fields. **The main shield grid was a massive replicator system**, projecting an invisible hull layer, molecularly identical to the diburnium-osmium alloy used to build the Kalandan outpost."

Answer (score 18):

Picard, in the TNG episode "[The Big Goodbye"](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/113.htm) confirmed that the holodeck can indeed create odours:

> **PICARD:** *From that window, I could see an entire, er*
>
> **DATA:** *City block.*
>
> **PICARD:** *That's right. Sounds, Smells.*
>
> **CRUSHER:** *You make it sound so real.*
>
> **PICARD:** *That's how it felt.*